# Publicar Sitio Blazor en servidor Apache-Cpanel

Tags: mysql, apache, blazor

Hice un desarrollo en Blazor Web Assembly (conexión a base de datos Mysql) y tengo un dominio alojado en un servidor Apache. Cómo puedo publicar este sitio de Blazor en este servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que procurar que el hosting que vayas a utilizar soporte asp.net core,  te recomiendo  smartasp.net, ese hosting soporta conexiones con bases de datos como sql server y mysql.